# Ajax data disappeared when I come back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web

I make a html page and there is ajax call for get some data.

after success ajax call, I render to html element with the json data which is from the ajax call.

But, If I go to other page by click some link, and when I come back there is no data at all.

how can I preserve the data element when I come back from other page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
...
...
<body>
<div id='data'>
</div>
<a href='/next'> NEXT </a>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : '/data/user',
    ...
    ...
    success: function(json) {
        $('#data').append(json.username);
    }
    ...
</script>
</html>
```

When I click 'NEXT' and history back. the username is go away.

Comment: You need to have some server side technology to load data from server. Ajax just modifies your `DOM` for single request.. Or do it in page load..

Comment: It is expected to lost data when you refresh the page or navigate another one. But if that ajax call is not based on a some condition; and that same data still exists on server side; it should be there even you refresh the page. Better if you share your code here.

Comment: you can either call the ajax inside the jquery ready function , so the username will be available everytime the page is visited or you can store it in a $_SESSION variable in your ajax file , and in your html page you can set the condition, if session not found make an ajax call to set the session

Comment: Call the ajax call in `$(document).ready(function(){ // your code here });`

Answer (score -1):

When page is reloaded all data came from ajax will be lost definitely. you can faster your ajax call if you already make ajax call earlier by using cache property

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  cache: true
})
  .done(function( html ) {
    $( "#results" ).append( html );
  });
```

Comment: I had set cache is true, but I lost data.

Comment: yes its going to be lost but that will make a little faster